# Class Instances holding a reference to themselves - self

Tags: c++

I've been learning C++ recently, and I've been trying to stick to the style that member functions and member variables should be explicitly referenced using this->.

However, I had a thought and developed a small class to test it:

```
class foo {
public:
    foo();
    size_t get_val() const;
    void set_val(const size_t p);
private:
    foo& self;
    size_t val;
};

foo::foo() : self(*this), val(0) {}
size_t foo::get_val() const { return self.val; }
void foo::set_val(const size_t p) { self.val = p; }
```

In which you can use self.bar instead of this->bar.

It compiled fine and I created a few instances and played around with it a bit and it seems to work okay (at least as far as I can tell), but I was simply wondering if, with non-trivial classes, this kind of definition could cause problems.

As a side note, I do realize that there's no real reason to do this. this->bar is literally only one character longer and doesn't require an additional data member in the constructor. I'm simply curious about doing this. So, for the purpose of this question, "pointless" doesn't really count as a problem.

Comment: Or you could use `#define self (*this)`, and not worry about this hack.

Comment: C++ programmers, when referring to `this`, use `this` keyword. That's the idiom. Use it, it works.

Comment: `So, for the purpose of this question, "pointless" doesn't really count as a problem.` Not really, pointless questions can receive bad answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem: it makes every object bigger by the size of one reference. The compiler can't optimize the member out of existence.

I guess you could actually use a macro like

```
#define SELF (*this)
```

to get the same effect, without paying the size cost.

Comment: Why can't the compiler optimize it out?

Comment: @BrianBi constructor can be in another module, and constructor"s" can be many. To optimize your code, I think high level link-time-optimization is required.

Comment: @ikh Forgive me for being a noob and not seeing something obvious, but how is that possible? You can't define the class twice and you can't define extra constructors besides the ones that were declared in the class definition... can you?

Comment: @BrianBi if we think that, I think you're right. But I don't think compiler is as smart as we are in this case.. anyway, my previous comment was a bit wrong..